# wamp 2.5 server configuration

Tags: javascript, php, apache, wamp

I'm using wamp 2.5, there are 2 different dev servers(a,b).Server A has frontend code and Server B has backend code and there is an connection between them in the Apache. Now we migrated front end and back end codes to cloud but facing some problems in connecting between them. Basically, In cloud the front end code and back end code have been saved in two different project folders in WAMP 2.5 and there is no issue with front end but problem is with back end. I feel that some change should be done in apache.

Comment: _"there is an connection between them in the Apache"_ <- can you explain further what this means?

Comment: by using proxy pass in apache the servers are connected